Why does the repository method return undefined in the test case after wrapping with async/await utility?
Why does it return error TypeError: undefined is not a spy or a call to a spy! from expect(userRepository.findUserById).not.toHaveBeenCalled(); in the test case after wrapping the repository's findUserId method with repoWrap from the AsyncWrapper class?
async-wrapper.util.ts
class AsyncWrapper {
  apiWrap = (cb: Function) => {
    return (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) =>
      cb(req, res, next).catch(
        next(ApiErrorException.HTTP500Error("Something went wrong"))
      );
  };

  serviceWrap = (fn: Function) => {
    return (...args: any) => {
      return fn.apply(this, args).catch((error: any) => {
        throw error;
      });
    };
  };

  repoWrap = (fn: Function) => {
    return (...args: any) => {
      return fn.apply(this, args).catch((error: any) => {
        throw DatabaseException.error(error);
      });
    };
  };
};

user.repository.impl.ts
class UserRepository implements IUserRepository {
  private database: Kysely<DB>;
  private wrap: AsyncWrapper = new AsyncWrapper();

  constructor() { this.database = db; };

  public findUserById = this.wrap.repoWrap(
    async (user_id: number): Promise<SelectUsers | undefined> => {
      return await this.database
        .selectFrom("users")
        .where("user_id", "=", user_id)
        .selectAll()
        .executeTakeFirst();
    }
  );
};

user.rervice.impl.ts
class UserService implements IUserService {
  private wrap: AsyncWrapper = new AsyncWrapper();
  private userRepository: UserRepository;

  constructor(userRepository: UserRepository) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
  }

  public getUserById = this.wrap.serviceWrap(
    async (id: number): Promise<SelectUsers | undefined> => {
      // If no parameters are provided, return an error
      if (!id) throw ApiErrorException.HTTP400Error("No arguments provided");

      // search the user by user_id
      const data = await this.userRepository.findUserById(id as any);

      // If the user is not found, return an error
      if (!data) throw ApiErrorException.HTTP404Error("User not found");
      return data;
    }
  );
};

user.service.spec.ts.ts
import UserRepository                                        from "@/repositories/user/user.repository.impl";
import { describe, test, expect, vi, beforeEach, afterEach } from "vitest";

vi.mock("@/repositories/user/user.repository.impl");

... other codes here
test("should throw an error when no args are provided", async () => {
 await expect(
   userService.getUserById(undefined as any)
 ).rejects.toThrow(noArgsMsgError);

 expect(userRepository.findUserById).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});


Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. "user.repository.impl" differs from "UserRepository.ts", it' not evident that you mocked the class, and it's unknown where userRepository comes from in "expect(userRepository.findUserById)", it's not defined in your code

hello @EstusFlask. I'm sorry for not being detailed but I updated the post the correct filename.

This isn't the only problem, please, check the comment. Your code will throw with "userRepository is not defined. The problem cannot be solved in its current state

If I remove the repoWrap then it will work as expected and if I just mock the  method like userRepository.findUserById = vi.fn(), it will work as well. The latter what I did but I am not much convinced in this way. Is there any other way? BTW it works if I perform it through API request.

This is about code you didn't show. It's unclear where userRepository variable comes from  whether the way you did this is possible to spy on its method's call inside userService. But since you mentioned the mock, this is a potential problem, since you rely on vitest's class automock that works in its own obscure way. I'm not sure if vitest has it documented at all, but it tries to mimic jest api which has it covered https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks at least, and you can't expect non-prototype methods from being analyzed outside a class.

Basically "findUserById" doesn't exist until original constructor runs, there's no way for test framework to be aware of it without instantiating original class, you can be pretty sure it doesn't do this because this would be a very undesirable side effect
So I'd suggest to write explicit UserRepository mock that fits your expectations instead of automocking it
